# Converting a table into another table with less rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, concatenation

I have a table in oracle db which consists of three fields (name,id,count). Id range is from 1 to 4 both including.

For example data in the table is like the following

```
+----+--+-----+
|Name|Id|Count|
+----+--+-----+
|A   |2 |5    |
+----+--+-----+
|A   |3 |15   |
+----+--+-----+
|B   |1 |10   |
+----+--+-----+
|B   |2 |12   |
+----+--+-----+
|B   |4 |6    |
+----+--+-----+
```

Now my problem is to make table like the following like name and ids in head section part and their counts in the corresponding position.

The result for the above example table will look like the following.

```
+----+------+------+------+------+
|Name|Id(=1)|Id(=2)|Id(=3)|Id(=4)|
+----+------+------+------+------+
|A   |0     |5     |15    |0     |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|B   |10    |12    |0     |6     |
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

I'm struck at this point. Is it possible to do ?
Please help me.

Appreciate ur help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pivot segregation. You can achieve using `case when ..` in your statement.

```
select 
 name,
 case `id` 
   when 1 then `count` else 0 end as 'id=1',
 case `id` 
   when 2 then `count` else 0 end as 'id=2',
 ...
from my_table
```

You can also use `if(...` function:

```
select 
 name,
 if(`id`=1, `id`, 0 ) as 'id=1',
 if(`id`=2, `id`, 0 ) as 'id=2',
 ...
from my_table
```